# ios9 - Xcode 7 - Swift - Keyboard shows correctly in Simulator but not on an actual Device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I'm experiencing an unusual issue where the keyboard correctly responds to input focus actions in the simulator (hardward keyboard disabled), but when I build and test on an actual device, the keyboard doesn't appear.

The app is a simple SFSafariViewController. Do I need to specify keyboard settings in Info.plist or something similar?

----- Update -----

Adding source code:

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    private var urlString:String = "https://example.com"

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        // This will remove the status (battery, time, etc) bar
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = true

        let svc = SFSafariViewController(URL: NSURL(string: self.urlString)!)

        // Kind of a hack, in that we really aren't removing the navbar
        //  Rather we are adjusting the starting point of the vpc object so it appears as the navbar is hidden
        self.presentViewController(svc, animated: true) {

            var frame = svc.view.frame
            let OffsetY: CGFloat = 42

            frame.origin = CGPoint(x: frame.origin.x, y: frame.origin.y - OffsetY)
            frame.size = CGSize(width: frame.width, height: frame.height + OffsetY)
            svc.view.frame = frame
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you attempting to respond to input focus?

Comment: I assume that it's being handled via default behavior via the SFSafariViewController. I added source code.

Comment: so you are saying that in simulator, you can type on your keyboard stuff and it'll work, but on a device, the keyboard never appears so nothing can be typed...right?

Comment: Correct. Simulator works fine. If I disable hardware keyboard and click on an input field, the focus is set as expected after which the keyboard is properly loaded. However, with no changes being made to the project, when I build on an actual iPhone, and click the same field, the keyboard never appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh. Being new to ios development I was 100% certain my code was borked, which was causing the keyboard not to appear. So this morning I created a test project and added each line of code from my project to the test project to see which was causing the perceived breakage.

After all the code was added back, I re-compiled the test project again, and it worked. Same exact code as the normal project, wtf? So then I realized there must be some caching anomaly that is causing the issue, and sure enough I found this [post](https://gist.github.com/riosc/4539602) on how to clear Xcode cache. After clearing the cache I re-loaded my project, re-compiled, and sure enough, my project worked as expected.

So in short, when in doubt, clear that cache.

Comment: The new XCode versions have been super buggy, feel your pain!

Comment: What sucks the most is I pulled the binary from iTunes connect thinking it was a code issue, so lost 4 days in queue :(